# How do I execute a sequence of commands by writing one line in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

With cmd.exe's interpreter this is easy:

```
echo testline > .\test.txt && c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe .\test.txt
```

What is the equivelent to this with bash?

For instance, vim doesn't execute when I run the following:

```
 ./check_nrpe -H 192.168.100.20 -c CheckEventLog -a MaxWarn=1 MaxCrit=1 file='Security' filter=out filter+eventType==auditFailure filter+generated=\<10m filter+eventID==534 filter+message=substr:'mbrown' descriptions > test1.csv && vim test1.csv
```

Does it have to do with the double redirector?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same in bash?

Comment: If you replaced notepad.exe with vi or some other editor, and fixed the slashes, then that command should run as written.

Comment: yes... corrected original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

&& works with short circuiting and second command will execute only if first command is correct. You can try using ; to separate two commands if it is ok for second command to execute unconditionally.

Comment: will they execute concurrently or sequentially when using the ; ?

Comment: the clue was in the answer. Read and understand before asking a question that has already been answered.

Comment: The ; separator will cause the commands to execute sequentially.  If you want the second command to start without waiting for the first to finish, try using & instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&&` separator. Just as cmd.exe.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to ad relative paths :'(

Comment: Just ran your amend and it worked perfectly - results.csv got written and vim opened it.